# Characters and combat mindset

Tags: system-agnostic

One of my main characters (a rather long-lived and notable one in the world she is in) has quite a considerable degree of combat mindset/mentality (hardening, if you will) imparted to her (i.e. not only is she capable of executing combat techniques  well, she is consistently effective and efficient in combat).  Atop this, she also is quite able to take her (typically very close) losses in stride, and will challenge foes several times, making adjustments in the process.

This has the severely problematic side-effect that many other players consider having their characters fight her as far more work than they are willing to invest, as they must rely on their ability to impart the mental aspects of combat (tactical decision-making, if you will) instead of simply assuming that the character who knows technique better likely will win, or waiting for the first mistake/opening to show up (while her style leaves openings, it also is aggressive enough to deny her foes the ability to exploit them readily).

So, where have I gone wrong? Is there some piece of the RP social code that says that RP characters shouldn't be as tactically-minded/combat-oriented as I have made mine?  Or is what I am doing with my character a problem for other players because they are making it into a problem for them?

Sidenote:
This is in a game where free-form combat RP is used fairly often, if that helps you; I am also speaking from a player perspective, as most RP in the game (it's a proto-MMO with a fairly sizeable RP community relative to the playerbase) is player-to-player, with no expressed 'plot leader' serving the storyline function of a GM/DM.  Obviously, this is also occurring without plot-specific NPCs, so most plot conflicts (and many of the RP-significant combat scenes) are between PCs to start with.

Comment: ... this doesn't seem like a system-agnostic question to me. Which RPG is this?

Comment: @Shal, are you a player or a GM?  This may well affect potential answers.

Comment: In this game, what function does PC-*versus*-PC combat serve? Why is it encouraged by the system, and what does your character lose by not having enough PC challengers? You want to know if you should courteously sandbag or keep steamrolling opposition, but without context the game's expectations are unknown.